# Solving Trig Equation with Unknown Inside and Outside of Function

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

In my physics course, we're covering physical pendulums, and we are to essentially analyze the range of angles within the interval $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{6}\right]$ to show that $\sin\theta \approx \theta$. (I completed [my analysis](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lfhbfccy2z) using Desmos.)

After creating our analyses, we are to estimate an angle, in radians, which has an error margin of approximately one percent. The error estimation function I have is
$$ E_1(x) = \frac{x - \sin x}{\sin x} \cdot 100, $$
where values of $x$ are in radians. I then rewrote the RHS as
$$ E_1(x) = (x\csc x - 1) \cdot 100. $$
So if the error threshold is one percent, I let $E_1(x) = 1$. And so I have been trying to figure out how to solve
$$ x \csc x - 1.01 = 0. $$
The best I could do was to graph the function on Desmos to find the roots.

However, I was hoping to get some pointers in the right direction as to how to solve this equation algebraically. While searching the Math Stack Exchange, I happened upon [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/926230), but the best I could gather is that the approach depends on the type of equation you have.

Is there a purely algebraic approach to solve this equation? Any advice and/or pointers to further reading would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, your instructor wants you to find the approximate value where the error is 1%. Your equation is transcendental and won't be solved algebraically.

You could use a numerical method such as [Newton's Method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/NewtonsMethod.aspx) to approximate the roots to desired accuracy. That presupposes your familiarity with calculus (or at least with differentiation).

Another alternative - which is what you did - is to solve it graphically, plotting $y_1=1$ and $y_2=\frac{x-\sin x}{\sin x}$ and assessing where they intersect visually. From your visual judgment, you can test (i.e. plug in) nearby values and, via trial and error, estimate where the error converges to 1%.

Comment: "Another alternative - which is what you did - is to solve it graphically" - this is precisely what our instructor wanted. My curiosity drove me to seek out other possible solutions. I forgot to mention I've had two semesters of calculus, but I had totally forgotten about the application of Newton's method. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Equations which contains polynomial and trigonometric functions do not show analytical solutions (this is the case for the simple $x=\cos(x)$) and, as zabbaz answered, numerical methods are required.

However, for this kind of problems where high accuracy is not required, some nice approximations can be done (may be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871516/how-could-i-improve-this-approximation) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska) could be of interest to you).

Considering the equation $$x \csc (x) - 1.01 = 0$$  or more generally $$x=a \sin(x)$$ (with $a >1$) we could use the magnificent approximation given more than $1400$ years ago  by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician. $$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ and then solve for $x$ equation  $$x=a\frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}$$ which reduces to the quadratic $$\left(16 \pi  a-5 \pi ^2\right)+(4 \pi -16 a) x-4 x^2=0$$ the solutionto be retained being $$x=-2 a+\frac{\pi }{2}+ \sqrt{4 a^2+2 \pi  a-\pi ^2}$$ For $a=1.01$, this leads to $x\approx 0.297$ while the exact solution (obtained using Newton method) would be $x\approx 0.244097$.

Since the solution is small, we could also have use Taylor series for the sine $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ which would lead to equation $$(a-1)-\frac{a x^2}{6}=0$$ the solution of which being $$x=\frac{\sqrt{6} \sqrt{a-1}}{\sqrt{a}}$$ For $a=1.01$, this would give  $x\approx 0.243733$.

Using one more term in the Taylor series would give $$(a-1)-\frac{a x^2}{6}+\frac{a x^4}{120}=0$$ which is a quadratic in $x^2$ and , for $a=1.01$, the solution would be $x\approx 0.244097$ which is almost the exact solution.

Comment: Very intriguing and quite clever! Thank you for the response and the links for further reading.

Comment: @Curtis. You are very welcome ! Just notice that the "small" assignment you were given is the same as a major problem I had in research !!